# Python how to find out the unique elements in a text file and output in another text file

Tags: python

I have a text file called sample.txt with the following content:-

```
abc  
abc
egf
abc 
xyz
efg
abc
xyz
efg
xyz
xyz
```

I want the to find out the unique elements and store it another text file called output.txt

Expected output:-

```
abc
efg
xyz
egf
```

Since I am new to python and Stackoverflow, can someone please help me out from the beginning itself? Thanks

Comment: _Since I am new to python and Stackoverflow, can someone please help me out from the beginning itself?_ -- So, so sweet.

Comment: Start here: [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Could you define _beginning_, please?

Comment: Have a look at set container

Comment: Lo! OP asks from the _beginning_ and they are talking Sets.

Comment: Order doesnt matter @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ

Comment: Your example shows duplicate elements as the result but the title says "unique". Please clarify.

Comment: Yes the example may contain duplicate elements but the output should contain only the unique ones

Comment: You missed `egf`. And, as others have mentioned, you can use `set` to only retain unique elements of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming output order is not important

```
with open('input_file','r') as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    distinct_content=set(f.readlines())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

to_file=""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
for element in distinct_content:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    to_file=to_file+element                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
with open('output_file','w') as w:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    w.write(to_file)
```

output:

```
efg
egf
xyz
abc
```

Comment: I hate to add a ``-1`` and downvote, but this is an awful answer.  There is no need for *f.readlines()*, just use ``set(f)``.  Never build-up strings using ``+=``.  Use ``''.join(list_of_strings)`` instead (the former is a quadratic algorithm and the latter is linear).  If you want to stick with a non-order preserving algorithm, the whole thing could boil down to ``w.writelines(set(f))``.  Everything else is a waste.

Answer (score 8):

If you're working in a Unix-like system, you don't need a *Python* script for that. Pipes and filters will suffice:

```
$ cat sample.txt | sort | uniq > output.txt
```

As @devnull points out, that can be written even more concisely as:

```
$ sort sample.txt | uniq > output.txt
```

If you really want to do it in Python:

```
seen = set()
with open('sample.txt') as infile:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if line not in seen:
                outfile.write(line)
                seen.add(line)
```

This will print the unique lines in the order they were first encountered.

A more terse way to do it uses [*collections.OrderedDict*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and the multi-context-manager form of the [with-statemen](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)t:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('sample.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(OrderedDict.fromkeys(infile))
```

Comment: @devnull I hope you retract the snarky comment.  The explanation is clearer using "cat" because it corresponds more closely with the parallel code in Python.  I hope you don't value clarity over conciseness when making explanations to beginners.  If someone doesn't know about the ``sort | uniq`` idiom, they aren't ready for all the short-cuts.

Comment: Done.  And thanks for those wonderful PyCon talks.  It's a treat watching those.

Comment: (I can't help adding that most of such users wouldn't care about any explanation.  All they want is a snippet of working code.  Efficiency, clarity, terse or verbose, doesn't really matter to such users.)

Comment: The fact that the "accepted answer" has a couple of downvotes attached to it would perhaps give a hint on what is really being looked for in answers.

Comment: Awesome! Great Job :)

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
try:
    with open(r'd:\text.txt') as f:
        l=[i.rstrip() for i in f]
    l=set(l)
    f1=open(r'd:\out.txt',"w")
    for i in l:
        f1.write(i)
        f1.write('\n')
    f.close()
    f1.close()
    print 'Done'
except Exception as e:
    print 'Error' , e
```

Comment: 1. Simply use `i.rstrip()`, the `split()` call is unnecessary. 2. No need to convert the set to a list. 3. Iterate over `f` itself rather than `f.readlines()`.

Comment: One last thing, always use the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) while handing files.

Answer (score 0):

Program uses only list and simple file operation.

```
element = raw_input("Element you want to find : ")
with open('sample.txt','r') as fp:
    listp = fp.readlines()
modifiedlist =[]
for i in range(0,len(listp)):
    word = listp[i]
    modifiedlist.append(word[0: len(word)-1])
print modifiedlist

fi = open('input.txt','w')
if element in modifiedlist:
    print element + "is present"
    fi.write(element)
fi.close()
```